# Is VBA name property is case sensitive

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have observed that below line of code works on one machine but not on other even though both machines have same office 2007 versions.

```
strName = folderObj.Name
```

But when I convert property from '.Name' to '**.n**ame' then it is observed to be working on machine on which it was not working earlier. Below are some of sample code lines for which I am encountering issues. Per my observation where ever earlier I mentioned .Name is failing on another machine:

```
strName = folderObj.Name
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Is there any setting which we may need to perform to ignore case for .name.

Comment: What happens when you put "Option Explicit" at the top of the code page?

Comment: I receive Type mismatch error even if I mention Option Explicit

Answer (score 1):

I remember dealing with a very similar issue a while back, but can't remember the specifics. I want say look for any references in your code to variables, properties, etc that are named 'name' (lower case) and change them to 'Name' (pascal case). I have a vague memory of VBA getting confused when you use different casing for items of the same name. (For the lack of a more technical explanation.) I know this doesn't really address the fact that it runs on one computer but not another, but it's worth a look.

Btw, when you say "it's not working" what error are you getting?